# How to change Gnome 42 window color

Tags: gnome, 22.04, gui, customization

Gnome 42 dark mode is kinda too dark for me. But the light mode is too bright. Honestly can't see the UI elements properly because of my eye problem. Is there any way to change the color of the window (title bar, background window etc).

Any editable files i can just use to change them?

Comment: have you looked at the `Accessibility` options concerning `Seeing`? For example. from `Settings` you can change to high contrast and other options and under `Appearance` there are options for different styles/themes and `GNOME Extension Manager` has an extension `User Themes` which you can install to experiment with.

Comment: Don't forget that any Gnome tweaks will miss the snaps, like firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically it is possible to alter certain colors of your windows by writing css in to a file located in

`~/.config/gtk-4.0/gtk.css` or `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`

But this can be a little tricky. Best option you'd have is to install `gnome-tweaks`, download a theme that suites you from [here](https://www.gnome-look.org/) and use gnome-tweaks to change them.

I've written some remarks on how to install a theme [here](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1424967/) and circumventing the [libadwaita](https://blogs.gnome.org/alatiera/2021/09/18/the-truth-they-are-not-telling-you-about-themes/) theme problem...

A user theme may then look like this:

[image]

Comment: thanks this is what i needed